# Dependency (but NOT compilation related) management tool

Tags: architecture, dependencies

We need a dependency management tool but not for computer languages. We have a large system with many interdependent components which we should like to manage dependency for. Additionally, we are releasing hotfixes dependencies between which should be managed automatically.

Can someone propose a tool for managing interdependency between components?

Comment: Could you please add some more details to your question? For example, do the components have a run-time dependency on each other? Which programming language are the components written in?

Comment: I cannot see how language or compile vs runtime dependency can affect generality of the problem. We need tool for general dependencies management. For exmaple it should answer the question: If I install this and that hotfix which pre-requisites it depends on.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.dsmweb.org/ there is a tools section which includes many tools for general dependency management.